Maintaining consistency of ESP on a pair of software RAIDed drives
If a Debian-based server is set up with two mirrored drives, done using mdadm,
How do you keep the EFI System Partition consistent across drives? As most BIOSes cannot read off of MDRaid partitions.
First thing I tried is setting the RAID up with metadata version 1.0, which should be put at the end of the ESP partition, so it appears "normal" to the BIOS
However, I found the ability to boot through that to be highly dependent on the specific BIOS, which varies across boards, making it non-ideal.
Second option is installing grub with the "--removable" switch, which makes it install itself into a "default fallback" EFI path. That only led me to GRUB loading up and going straight to "Reset system" and rebooting.
I don't even know how to debug this, considering it happens before even the kernel or initrd gets loaded.


How do you keep the EFI System Partition consistent across drives? As most BIOSes cannot read off of MDRaid partitions.

Usually: not at all; these devices are written to and read from so rarely that automatic mirroring has no advantage.
So, just rsync over the files between the FAT32 partitions each successful boot. (You could also add a hook to be triggered when you do any GRUB updates, but I'm not versed enough in debian to know how that would work.)

A simple rsync would not be enough though, I'd also have to constantly re-register the pair of bootloaders in EFI, as EFI boot entries are drive-specific, e.g.:
Boot0000: * debian HD(1,GPT,65ebe624-b5f8-41a7-90f0-242b6494df33,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\DEBIAN\SHIMX64.EFI)
And that just sounds... Dirty. So I'm asking to see if there is a more universal approach.

@Aldar You will always have to manually register the bootloader – EFI as an API says you need to do that. But also, unless you commonly update your EFI shim, that will never have to happen. So, not sure you're solving a problem worth solving here!
